# How to deal with Avro to BigQuery type conversions when using LoadJobs with auto schema retrieval

Tags: google-bigquery, avro

We have defined a company wide shared model in Avro and would like to load this model data into BigQuery using `LoadJobs` with auto schema retrieval and later be able to export the data (to Google Cloud Storage or somewhere else) and deserialize/read it using the same Avro model.

The problem with this approach is that the exported Avro schema is different from the loaded schema and therefor the deserialization, using the same schema as for the loading, fails.

We see the following incompatible type conversions:

| Model schema (used when loading) | Derived BigQuery type | Schema (after export) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `int` | `INTEGER` | `long` |
| `float` | `FLOAT` | `double` |
| `time-millis` | `TIME` | `time-micros` |
| `timestamp-millis` | `TIMESTAMP` | `timestamp-micros` |
| `map` | `REPEATED RECORD` | `array` |

Fmpov I only see the following solutions to this problem:

1. Create table+schema upfront instead of using auto-retrieval
2. Use adapters when loading into and/or exporting from BigQuery
3. Change the Avro schema to use types which are "compatible" (that are not changed between load and export) with BigQuery

Any further ideas?

Comment: Can you confirm if the reproduction steps are:
1 - Load a avro schema
2- Export it from BQ
3-  then the data types are different?

Comment: @JaimeLopez yes, the steps are 1. LoadJob from avro container file 2. ExportJob from BQ. Looks like this: https://gist.github.com/leozilla/2fb36fa3ec98face4fff5d1161c50a3a

Answer (score 0):

When you export some data from BigQuery to Avro format, it’ll create a scheme without the possibility of defining a custom one. You can check the target Avro field type depending on the BigQuery scheme [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#avro_export_details).

Your first idea about creating a table upfront instead of using auto-retrieval doesn’t seem to be a useful workaround because in your situation there aren’t BigQuery types that match with your Avro schema when you export them.

Using adapters seems to be the best option in your case, and maybe exporting the [date and datetime from BigQuery as milliseconds](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#unix_millis) directly can make your life easier. Also, depending on what you do on BigQuery, you can also think about don’t use Avro logical types when you import the data into BigQuery, but there is again a way to make an adapter implementation easier, not a solution to avoid the usage of them.